# Find a obfuscation tool for android package built from Unity 4.*

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, obfuscation

I have done a game used **Unity** engine, written in C#, now I want to publish a **Android version to Google play**. But currently, I know many games might be hacked if we don't obfuscate the code.

I checked [this](http://www.4infinity.com.hk/tutorial/code_obfuscation) many times, but not successful yet.

Does anyone know any another tool support this?

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

You can take a look at Eazfuscator.NET. We delivered automatic obfuscation technology for Unity applications that just works:

http://www.gapotchenko.com/eazfuscator.net/features/gaming-technologies/unity

Not only Android, but also iOS, Windows Phone and others are covered.

Answer (score 0):

There are few code obfuscation tools for unity, but in order to use them well with your code some guidelines need to be kept in mind while coding,
  so you might need to change your code in some places,
most of the code obfuscation tools don't have proper documentation for using with android .

you can see the following detailed link of the unity code obfuscation tool and how to use it with android

http://www.4infinity.com.hk/tutorial/code_obfuscation

Comment: I tried it many times, but not successful yet.