# Integrating Dotfuscator into Unity3D build pipeline

Tags: unity-game-engine, mono, dotfuscator

I am trying to use Dotfuscator with Unity3D. When building my Android project in Unity, it uses it's internal mono compiler. I added 'AfterBuild' target to '.csproj' file and if I build project in Visual Studio 2013, AfterBuild works.

So my question is, how can I modify Unity's build pipeline for this?

I am using Unity 5.4.2 and VS 2013.

Answer (score 0):

For desktop app,

1. Use [`BuildPipeline.BuildPlayer`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/BuildPlayerPipeline.html)
   to build your app or game into a specified path. Then use Dotfuscator to obfuscate the dll(it should be located somewhere in the ouput directory), by starting a Dotfuscator process when the build

   ```
   // Build player.
   BuildPipeline.BuildPlayer(levels, path + "/BuiltGame.exe", BuildTarget.StandaloneWindows, BuildOptions.None);

   // Obfuscate the dll in the player.
   Process proc = new Process();
   proc.StartInfo.FileName = "path_to_dotfuscator";
   proc.StartInfo.Arguments = "arguments_of_dotfuscator path_to_app_dll";
   proc.Start();
   ```
2. Use [command line of the Unity3D Editor](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/CommandLineArguments.html) to build your app or game. Then use Dotfuscator to obfuscate the dll. Just use a script language as you wish to write and run these steps.

For iOS/Mac app, use **il2cpp** should be enough to *obfuscate* the app. I'm not absolutely sure about that, though.

For Android, I don't know if there is a way to intercept the building pipeline before Unity3D make the apk for you. But we can always extract the dll from the apk, obfuscate it and put it back. There does exist some solutions for this, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17232236/find-a-obfuscation-tool-for-android-package-built-from-unity-4).